# Soma com Números Negativos e Positivos - Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando realizar a soma de valores positivos e negativos no banco de Dados SqlServer, porém o mesmo feito pela calculadora retorna um valor diferente.

Estou usando

```
SUM(NR_QUANTIDADE)
```

A coluna NR_QUANTIDADE é do tipo float no banco de dados.

Os meus valores no banco de dados são:

```
-9,9961
-30,41
-19,5939
60
```

Já o resultado do meu select está retornando:

```
-5,32907051820075E-15
```

E o certo seria retornar 0.

Comment: Insira seu select aqui

Comment: Seu problema não é de números positivos ou negativos mas de precisão pq é impossível para o computador ter precisão infinita e por isso sempre há imprecisões ao lidar com números decimais. Há muitas questões sobre isso aqui no site, pode deletar essa questão que é redundante é procurar por posts como esses:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+erro+arredondamento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Montei um exemplo em base do que você postou:

```
create table temp (valor float)

insert into temp (valor) values (-9.9961)
insert into temp (valor) values (-30.41)
insert into temp (valor) values (-19.5939)
insert into temp (valor) values (60)

select sum(valor) total from temp
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2cd33d/1/0